# Is it possible to override Value on a nullable struct, to return a diffrent type?

Tags: c#, struct, nullable

This might sound crazy to you, but I need a `Nullable<T>` (where T is a struct) to return a different type for it's Value property.

Rules being if `Nullable<T>`'s Property HasValue is true, Value will always return an object of a different specified type (then itself).

I might be over thinking this, but this unit test bellow kind of shows what I want to do.

```
    public struct Bob
    {
            ...
    }


    [TestClass]
    public class BobTest
    {
            [TestMethod]
            public void Test_Nullable_Bob_Returns_Joe()
            {
                    Joe joe = null;
                    Bob? bob;
                    var bobHasValue = bob.HasValue; // returns if Bob is null

                    if(bobHasValue)
                            joe = bob.Value; //Bob returns a Joe
            }
    }
```

Comment: It definitely shows WHAT you want to do, but... why? And how would your Bob know what Joe to return?

Comment: I would write the logic in the overloaded property, or what not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Are you look for a [user-defined implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=VS.71).aspx?ppud=4)?** If so, you can define one on Bob:

```
class Bob {
    static public implicit operator Joe(Bob theBob) {
       // return whatever here...
    }
}
```

**If you can't do this because you don't have access to change `Bob`,** you could always consider writing an extension method:

```
public static class BobExt {
    public static Joe ToJoe( this Bob theBob ) {
        return whatever; // your logic here...
    }
}

if(bobHasValue) 
    joe = bob.Value.ToJoe(); // Bob converted to a Joe
```

Comment: Nice one! Don't you want an `implicit` though?

Comment: @Kobi: Haha. I need to cut back on the coffee. Yes, thank you - I fixed my example.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the conversion operator is not required to be defined within the class.

Comment: @Zach Johnson: I don't this so. Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x7fay24(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @LBushkin:  Oops!  Yes, you are correct.  I sure thought I remembered doing it at one point, but I guess not...

Comment: I think implicit conversion could work well in what I am trying to accomplish, thank you.